# Parsing unstructured text file with grep

Tags: bash, parsing, grep

I am trying to analyze this IDS log file from MIT, [found here](https://archive.ll.mit.edu/ideval/files/master-listfile-condensed.txt).

```
Summarized attack: 41.084031
 IDnum    Date       StartTime Duration Destination    Attackname insider? manual? console?success? aDump? oDump iDumpBSM? SysLogs FSListing StealthyNew? Category OS
 41.08403103/29/1999 08:18:35  00:04:07 172.016.112.050ps         out              rem     succ     aDmp   oDmp  iDmp BSM  SysLg   FSLst     Stlth   Old  llU2R 
 41.08403103/29/1999 08:19:37  00:01:56 209.154.098.104ps         out              rem     succ     aDmp   oDmp  iDmp BSM  SysLg   FSLst     Stlth   Old  llU2R 
 41.08403103/29/1999 08:29:27  00:00:43 172.016.112.050ps         out              rem     succ     aDmp   oDmp  iDmp BSM  SysLg   FSLst     Stlth   Old  llU2R 
 41.08403103/29/1999 08:40:14  00:24:26 172.016.112.050ps         out              rem     succ     aDmp   oDmp  iDmp BSM  SysLg   FSLst     Stlth   Old  llU2R
```

I am trying to write commands that do two things:

1. First, parse through the entire file and determine the amount of distinct "summarized attacks" that begin with 4x.xxxxx. I have accomplished this with:
   `grep -o -E "Summarized attack: 4"`. It returns `80`.
2. Second, for each of the "Summarized Attacks" found by the above command, parse the table and determine the amount of `IDnum` rows, and return the total amount of rows (i.e., attacks) across all "Summarized attack" finds. I would imagine that number is somewhere around `200`.

However, I am struggling to get the individual number of IDs, i.e., that are in the `IDnum` column of this text file.

Since it is a text file with technically no structure, how can I parse this `.txt` file as if it had a tabular structure to retrieve the total entries in the `IDnum` column, for each `Summarized attack` that follows the above `grep` command's search text?

Desired output would be a count of all IDnum's for the Summarized attacks found by the above command. I don't know the count, but I would imagine an integer output, similar to the return of `80` for `grep -o -E "Summarized attack: 4"`. The output would be `<int>` where `<int>` is the # of "attacks" as defined by rows in the `IDnum` column across all 80 of the found "Summarized attacks" by the above grep command.

If another command other than `grep` is better suited, that is OK.

Comment: Hi @Cyrus. I'm not sure what quite more to add. I've updated the question. The intention would be to take the parsing I have completed thus far, and take it one step further, to now parse the tables found by my command. Since the structure of the file is text, and not tabular, I don't know how to do that. What else am I missing?

Comment: do you want to grep week 4 only or do you need generic regex for all weeks

Comment: `grep` means "**G**lobally match a **R**egular **E**xpresion and **P**rint the result". That's more than you want to do so `grep` is the wrong tool for the job, you should be figuring out how to do it with `awk`. If your rea data can have more than one "Summarized attack" in it then show at least 2 in your sample input/output.

Comment: wundermahn what @Cyrus means is that in every question you should post concise, testable sample input **and** the output you expect given that input. Without that your question is much less clear and we don't have anything to test a potential solution against to know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton. Sorry for not doing that. I thought posting a link to the file in question, a sample of that link, and my expected output (an integer, stated in question) all answered the question. How do you suggest I improve? Add more copy and paste from the specified link? Sorry, this is different than the normal `sql` or `python` communities I am in. Making sure I understand.

Comment: @wundermahn no problem. "an integer" is a description of your output, it's not an example of your output. Good questions don't contain links or images, just a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input (that you made up to demonstrate your problem with minimal data - NOT just a snapshot of your large real data) and expected output (the exact output given your posted sample input) plus your code showing your attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have more than one "Summarized attack:" in your input file this may be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^Summarized attack:/ {
    prt()
    atk = ($3 ~ /^4/ ? $3 : 0)
    cnt = 0
}
atk { cnt++ }
END {
    prt()
    print "TOTAL", tot
}

function prt() {
    if ( atk ) {
        cnt -= 2
        print atk, cnt
    }
    tot += cnt
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

Answer (score 2):

1. to count matches you can use grep `-c`

   ```
   grep -cE '(^Summarized.attack:.4[0-9]\.[0-9]+$)'
   ```
2. you can use colon as delimiter for cut `-d`
   (if you loop over results the leading whitespace does not care)

   ```
   grep -oE '(^Summarized.attack:.4[0-9]\.[0-9]+$)' | cut -d: -f2
   ```

example loop

```
   file="path/to/master-listfile-condensed.txt"
   for var in $(grep -oE '(^Summarized.attack:.4[0-9]\.[0-9]+$)' "$file" | cut -d: -f2)
     do
       printf "Summarized attacks: %s: %s\n" $var \
       $(grep -cE "(^.${var}[0-9]+/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})" "$file")
   done
```

`^` start of line
`$` end of line
`.` any byte (in this case single whitespace)
`\.` single dot (escaped)
`[0-9]` single digit
`+` one (or more) occurrence
`{4}` four occurrence

Comment: `grep -cE '(^.4[0-9]\.[0-9]+/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})'` for across all

Comment: please note that regex/loop only work for `LF` (linefeed) and not for `CRLF` (carriage return) line endings. therefore you should specify the format of input file or just delete the `$` sign from grep to make the regex more generic (or convert the input with `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`)

Answer (score 0):

For your first part, `fgrep -c "Summarized attacks: 4"` or `fgrep -F "Summarized attacks: 4"` is sufficient.

If I understand your second part, for each of those blocks, you want to add up the attack rows and print a grand total. You can do that with

```
gawk '/^Summarized attack: 4/ { on=1; next} /^ 4[0-9.]*/ { if (on) ++ids; next} /^ IDnum/ {next} /^ */ {next} { on=0} END {print ids;}'< master-listfile-condensed.txt
```

The first statement says, search (`/.../`) for every line that begins with (`^`) "Summarized attack: 4", and upon finding it, turn on the "on" flag, and go to the next line.  The second statement says, if this is an attack record (i.e. begins with  `4` followed by a string [`*`] of digits), then check the flag; if it is on, count it. Basically, we want the flag to be on when we are in a stanza of target attack records. The next two statements say for every line that starts with " IDnum" or are all whitespace (sometimes blank lines are inserted), go to the next line; this is needed to counteract the next statement, which says that if this is not a line that matches any of the previous statements, turn off the "on" flag. This prevents us from counting attacks outside the target. Finally, `END` means at the end, print the grand total. I get `757` which is pretty far out of your range. But I think it is correct.

But a far easier way, assuming the Summarized timestamp is always repeated in the IDnum at least to the first significant digit, would be to use

```
grep -Ec '^ 4' master-listfile-condensed.txt
```

That means count all the lines that begin with space-4. In this case it gives us the correct result.